# Tidekit and C#/Java/C++ native code compatibility

Tags: c#, java, c++, native, tidekit

I am interested in this new platform - Tidekit. But I couldn't find any answer to my questions:

1. Is it possible to add C# (or at least C++/JAVA) code or Dll libraries to the solution?
2. Is it possible to make a package with html+js+css and native code (C#/C++/Java) working in one executable file or executable + dlls?

There are already working solutions like CefSharp, Awesomium, but there is a problem to make external resources (html, css, js) embedded inside the project.

I would like to hide my implementation from end users somehow.

I'll appreciate any answer related to my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. We don't support C#, but yes to the rest.
2. Again, no C#, but yes to answer this question.

Further explanation below:

We've developed TideKit to have a small and stable core so that the apps can be built up in a modular way with the functionality you want in your app. TideKit provides simultaneous extension in ObjC++, C++, Java, and JavaScript for web, HTML5 hybrid and native apps. 
Generally, developers will consume modules without the need to write lower level code because the functionality already exists both natively and for HTML at the same time. So mostly it is about consuming modules and writing your app in JavaScript.

Modules allow a project to be built for desktop, mobile and web from a single base of code. TideKit is a uniquely develop once, deploy everywhere platform with easy-to-use JavaScript APIs and CommonJS modularity. The best way to write TideKit apps is CommonJS. More than 60K modules of CommonJS functionality is available through npm and components registries. Folks familiar with nodejs will be at home with it. You can also write conventional JavaScript or easily migrate an existing TideSDK app.

Automated packaging, installers, and distribution are part of our solution. There are packaging options that can provide bundled or network installs to take advantage of dynamic libraries for efficient runtime code to keep the amount of installable and distributable code to a minimum.

TideKit has the capability to build in different ways from your project source to optimize for AppStore compliance or even highest HTML5 compliance. You can use it to build HTML5 or native apps for virtually any platform you wish to support. On the backend, we have capabilities for the widest range of mobile and desktop operating systems and for web deployments. Beyond building your app simultaneously for multiple platforms, you can also develop, test, and deploy your APIs from the same base of code.

Our build service protects your code from exposure by encrypting and embedding the sources in a binary. Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, you have ruby, so you could possibly get ffi to work, and then run the dll through there: [ffi example](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/wiki/Windows-Examples)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible to use DLL's with something in between using Ti.Process...

the idea to execute a DLL is to have something in return (a very especific process, only for windows desktop I believe). I'm facing the same challenge but I guess I will approach to Ambiance Air App which uses a DLL to validate the license of the product...

in short it could be

```
var myScript = Ti.Process.createProcess({
    args:['python',Ti.API.application.resourcesPath + "/??????"] 
    //the unknown command for the exe that uses the dll? it should return an object! not even functions...
});

myScript.myObject;
```